# Initial value in useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is there a point in having the initial value in useState be an empty array in this case :

```
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('/shoes')
      .then((res) => {
        setProducts(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

When should i have initial values and when not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an initial state which is the same *shape* as the result can make working with the stateful variable later easier. For example, if you use the empty array as the initial state, later, you'll be able to do:

```
return (
  <div>
    {products.map(prod => <span>{prod.name}</span>)}
  </div>
);
```

Whereas if you *didn't* use an initial state, you'd have to make sure that `products` existed first:

```
return (
  <div>
    {products?.map(prod => <span>{prod.name}</span>)}
  </div>
);
```

or

```
return (
  <div>
   {products && products.map(prod => <span>{prod.name}</span>)}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you for your quick answer

Answer (score 1):

We usually handle our `error` scenario, our `loading` scenario within our initial API call itself. And API call is made from the `useEffect()`.

But, `useEffect()` hook is invoked only after the initial render of our JSX. To handle all the above scenarios it is always best to keep the initial values of state with their appropriate data types.

Secondly, we could also have many `useEffect()` Hooks within the same React Component handling their respective tasks because `useEffect()` does take 2nd argument as list of states in an array - acting as componentDidUpdate() life cycle hook, so to have the knowledge of what state and its type we are going to use in later part of application and keeping it in `useState()` initially allows working with the data easy.